# Equation of Trajectory of particle following a given condition

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, vectors, physics

> A cat moves along the x-axis with a uniform velocity u. A dog moves with a uniform speed $v$ such that at every moment it is aimed towards the cat. Initially, at $t = 0$, the dog is perpendicular to the cat at a distance $l$ away from it. Find the equation of the trajectory of the dog.

**My Approach:**

(I used a hand-drawn diagram because I can't draw digitally)

[image]

Suppose the dog has a velocity $v$ at a given instant (say at time $t$). Now, its velocity vector shifts as shown in the figure after a time $dt$ when the cat travels a distance $u$  $dt$.
Now, clearly these shown triangles are similar.
Thus, we get
$$\frac{v \space \sin \theta}{y} = \frac{v \space  d\theta}{u \space dt}$$
$$\implies dt = \frac{y \space  d\theta}{u \space \sin \theta}$$
Now, we know,
$$dy = v \space \sin \theta \space dt$$
$$\implies dy = v \space \sin \theta \space \frac{y \space  d\theta}{u \space \sin \theta}$$
$$\implies \frac{dy}{y} =   \frac{v \space  d\theta}{u }$$
$$\implies \int_{l}^{y} \frac{dy}{y} =   \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}  \frac{v \space  d\theta}{u }$$
$$\implies \ln( \frac{y}{l}) =   \frac{v \space  (\theta - \frac{\pi}{2} )}{u }$$
$$\therefore y =   l\space e^{\frac{v \space  (\theta - \frac{\pi}{2})}{u }}$$
Now, I tried using the fact that $\frac{dy}{dx} = \tan \theta$ but the expression I obtained for $x$ in terms of $\theta$ was not something I could integrate. Please suggest how to compute for $x$ and if this flow of logic is correct.

Comment: [Radiodrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiodrome). [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244333/cat-dog-problem-using-integration/246113#246113) .

Comment: Also [linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236504/a-martin-gardner-arclength-problem/2237308#2237308), and [also](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4224855/is-there-a-name-or-some-sort-of-definition-for-a-curve-traced-by-one-object-movi/4224858#4224858).

Comment: Thanks! But could you please confirm if this method is correct